# mysqli_error: updating tables (Procedural style)

Tags: php, mysqli, updating

I am using PHP to try and update information I have in a mysqli table. I have decided to try and use mysqli rather than mysql. Unfortunately I cant seem to find my answer anywhere because im also trying to complete it Procedural style, as I have no knowledge of OOP and all tutorials (that i have found) are in OOP.

Below is the script I have created. I have added comments to say what I think each command is doing.

```
<?php    
DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_PASS', 'password');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'test');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

//connect to db
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_connect_error($dbc));
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

//form not submitted
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE people_id = $_GET[id]";//compares id in database with id in address bar
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);//query the database
    $person = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//returns results from the databse in the form of an array

}else{//form submitted

    $q = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE people_id = $_POST[id]";//compares id in database with id in form
    $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);//query the database
    $person = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//returns results from the database in an array

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $hobby = $_POST['hobby'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    //mysqli code to update the database
    $update = "UPDATE people
               SET    people_fname = $fname,
                      people_lname = $lname,
                      people_age = $age,
                      people_hobby = $hobby
               WHERE  people_id = $id";

    //the query that updates the database
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $update) or die(mysqli_error($r));

    //1 row changed then echo the home page link
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1){    
        echo "<a href=\"index.php\">home page</a>";
    }
}
?>
```

The update form

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <p>First name<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo "$person[people_fname]" ?>" /></p>
    <p>Last name<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo "$person[people_lname]" ?>" /></p>
    <p>Your age<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo "$person[people_age]" ?>" /></p>
    <p>Your hobby<input type="text" name="hobby" value="<?php echo "$person[people_hobby]" ?>" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" />        
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="MODIFY" />
</form>`
```

When I submit the form I get the following error message

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\update.php on line 39
```

I realize this is telling me the issue is with

`$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $update) or die(mysqli_error($r));`

So I have tried to put the sqli code in as the second parameter (i realize this is the same as putting the variable in, but it was a last resort), but it didn't seem right and still didn't work. I have also looked a php.net but couldn't work out the answer from the example they have given

Please advise, I thought this was meant to be simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass `$r` to mysqli_error. It accepts an optional mysql link, but not a query result anyway.

In your case, the query is executed. That evaluates to false, which is assigned to `$r`. The assignment evaluates to false, causing you to call `die(mysqli_error($r))` with `$r` being false.

I think you meant to pass `$dbc` to mysqli_error.

Answer (score 1):

```
$update = "UPDATE people
           SET    people_fname = $fname,
                  people_lname = $lname,
                  people_age = $age,
                  people_hobby = $hobby
           WHERE  people_id = $id";
```

You need to quote out the variables:

```
$update = "UPDATE people
           SET    people_fname = '$fname',
                  people_lname = '$lname',
                  people_age = '$age',
                  people_hobby = '$hobby'
           WHERE  people_id = '$id'";
```

**HOWEVER**

You should look into bound parameters - you're taking user input and writing it straight into your database, which means that a malicious user can do all sorts of mischief.

Have a look at the manual page for [mysqli's bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) - there are plenty of example code snippets.

Comment: Thankyou, that sorted out the update problem. I will take a look at mysqli's bind_param

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the problem is with the database connection ($dbc). Because you are using

```
@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
```

The '@' may be hiding the connection error somehow.

Also, please tell me you're doing data sanitisation in real life, right? If not, you have to run mysqli_real_escape_string() on all the POST and GET data.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. Yeah, i will be doing, at the moment I am just trying to get my head around using php and mysqli, once I have a better understanding of that I will look at security...there is so much to learn I have had to break it into my manageable chunks.

Answer (score -1):

you wrote

```
//returns results from the database in an array
$person = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

but you should write

```
//returns results from the database in an array
$person = mysqli_fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: The procedural style function expects a `mysqli_result` _and_ an optional result type. Your answer won't work.